# Sci-fi book series featuring insectoid aliens, motorized armor and main character in anabiosis

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens, space-colonization

I remember not too much about this book series, but I know exactly:

1. It was written before 2000 (70-80's maybe).
2. Series includes at least 3 books, maybe more.
3. Space opera.
4. Main character is a male soldier, fighting in some kind of motorized armor (exoskeleton?). Soldier was in suspended animation during flight to one of the fights, but something on his ship broke and he slept for too long and was the last survivor of his squad. In one of the books hero starts to think that his armor has its own mind.
5. Humanity has settled in galaxy, but is at war with bug-kind insectoid race.
6. In one of the books, main character meets ambassador of these bugs.
7. Main character saves a girl from slavery or something like that, later she falls in love with him.

This book is not *Armor* by John Steakley, and not *Starship Troopers*.

Comment: It sounds like 'The Bug Wars'

Comment: Hmm... would they have thought to mention the protagonist being a lizard? https://nicksheridan.com/craplookingbooks/clb-12-robert-asprin-the-bug-wars/

Comment: @DannyMcG no, it's not 'The Bug Wars', protagonist is a human.

Comment: Just stating while it sounds similar to it, it is also different enough to the [Legacy of the Aldenata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_of_the_Aldenata) to rule it out.

Comment: If your pupils are dilated from a trip to the eye doctor, you could almost read this as *The Forever War* et sequelae.  Powered armor, check.  Liquid suspension for high-gee maneuvers could read as suspended animation.  Potter was never a slave, Mandella met her in training.  Enemy was vaguely insectoid, but at least in the first book, Mandella never met an ambassador.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The six-part series you are looking for is [*The Sand Wars*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?12681) (1987-1990) by Charles Ingrid. It matches all seven of your criteria perfectly. I read them when they first appeared in the late 1980's; the story is a quick read, but I enjoyed them as a younger man and recently re-read them many years later and found them still a good read. Brief synopsis [from Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/series/61577-sand-wars):

> Jack Storm was the last of the Dominion Knights--the human soldiers who defended their empire against an alien foe. Not only is Jack the sole survivor of the Thrakian invasion called The Sand War; he is also the owner of a unique battle suit--a suit of sentient armor that feeds off him while at the same time making him a super soldier!

Comment: @KellyW, you goddam right, that's it! Thank you 